# php curl works from cli but not from apache

Tags: php, curl, apache2

I can't get cURL to work from inside Apache by any means. It's actually fairly strange too provided that:

1. I can execute my PHP pages from the CLI and it POSTs my requests perfectly fine
2. When I look at my error logs, I get "PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function curl_init()" as if the extension isn't installed at all. Similarly, a quick `phpinfo()` also yields such as if the extension isn't installed.

Additionally, when I built PHP, I opted the "--enable-curl" flag.

Comment: There are a different php.ini for the CLI and Apache maybe you Apache php.ini is not loading CURL

Answer (score 2):

You are probably not loading the extension in the appropriate `php.ini`. The file should include something like:

```
[PHP_CURL]
extension=php_curl.dll
```

Also, `--enable-curl` is not a PHP configure option. `--with-curl=[DIR]` is the one you'd want. Check out the [cURL installation instructions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.setup.php).

`php_curl.dll` should be inside PHP's `ext` directory when configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem after installing php5-curl. I rebooted apache and that fixed it.

sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart for ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem - worked from cli, silently failed from Apache 2.4

I've tried:

1) copying ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll from php folder into apache\bin folder - didn't work

2) deleting ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll from apache\bin folder completely - WORKED.

You should restart apache server each time you make change to make it work.

Also you should install both x86 and x64 versions of C++ Resistributable Visual Studio from [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52982).